# How do you style the submit button on a UINavigationBar using UIAppearance?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm styling my iOS app with [UIApperance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). I have managed to make all the bar button items in all my [UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)s have gray text, except one particular button - the send button of the view of [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) remains as its default white color. Why does my code target every button except this one?

[image]

```
NSDictionary* normalStyle = [NSDictionary 
    dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray 
        arrayWithObjects:
            [UIColor navigationTextNormalColor],
            [UIColor whiteColor],
            [NSValue 
                valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(
                    0, 
                    1
                )
            ]
            , nil
        ]
        forKeys:[NSArray
            arrayWithObjects:
                UITextAttributeTextColor,
                UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                nil
        ]
];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
    setTitleTextAttributes:normalStyle
    forState:UIControlStateNormal
];

[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] 
    setTintColor:[UIColor navigationBarTintColor]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

> Important The mail composition interface itself is not customizable
>   and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make
>   further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the
>   content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored.
>   Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the
>   interface.

Comment: I don't suppose the UINavigationBar is part of the mail composer's view because it lies outside of its hierarchy.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to work around the issue.  You can customize the color/background but that's about it.  Basically they don't want anyone to be able to trick someone into sending off an email.